# WooCommerce: How to order by IDs specified in shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I have page in WooCommerce, in which I am showing my specific categories, for that I have used WooCommerce shortcode

```php
[product_categories ids="1494,349,2671,375,2724,1522,1635,1511,1508,1523,2929,1489,2881,2791,1517,375" columns="3"]
```

---

Here you can see i have defined id `1494, 349, 2671` etc...., I want to do ordering same as that id order, is there any trick which I can use for it? any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `orderby = "include"` attribute to order by the ids.

Available Product Category attributes

- `ids` – Specify specific category ids to be listed. To be used in [product_categories]
- `category` – Can be either the category id, name or slug. To be used in [product_category]
- `limit` – The number of categories to display
- `columns` – The number of columns to display. Defaults to 4
- `hide_empty` – The default is “1” which will hide empty categories. Set to “0” to show empty categories
- `parent` – Set to a specific category ID if you would like to display all the child categories
- `orderby` – The default is to order by “name”, can be set to “id”, “slug”, or “menu_order”. If you want to order by the ids you specified then you can use `orderby="include"`
- `order` – States whether the category ordering is ascending `(ASC)` or descending `(DESC)`, using the method set in orderby. Defaults to `ASC`.

Source: [[product_categories] - Shortcode](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#section-13)

---

So you get

```php
[product_categories ids="1494,349,2671,375,2724,1522,1635,1511,1508,1523,2929,1489,2881,2791,1517,375" columns="3" orderby="include"]
```

Comment: orderby="include" seems to no longer work and was removed from the documentation. Had to resort to adding my own foreach loop which isn't a great solution, no idea why WC wouldn't retain this functionality.